# Image corrupted after zooming

Tags: image, kinect, emgucv

I am reading color frame from Kinect V2 sensor using Microsoft Kinect SDK v2. I am copying the frame data in a byte array, which is later on converted into EmguCV Image. Below is the snippet from the code-

```
// A pixel buffer to hold image data from the incoming color frame
private byte[] pixels = null;
private KinectSensor kinectSensor = null;
private ColorFrameReader colorFrameReader = null;
public KinectForm()
{
    this.kinectSensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();
    this.colorFrameReader = this.kinectSensor.ColorFrameSource.OpenReader();
    this.colorFrameReader.FrameArrived += this.Reader_ColorFrameArrived;
    // create the colorFrameDescription from the ColorFrameSource using Bgra format
    FrameDescription colorFrameDescription = this.kinectSensor.ColorFrameSource.CreateFrameDescription(ColorImageFormat.Bgra);
    // Create a pixel buffer to hold the frame's image data as a byte array
    this.pixels = new byte[colorFrameDescription.Width * colorFrameDescription.Height * colorFrameDescription.BytesPerPixel];
    // open the sensor
    this.kinectSensor.Open();
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Reader_ColorFrameArrived(object sender, ColorFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    using (ColorFrame colorFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
    {
        if (colorFrame != null)
        {
            FrameDescription colorFrameDescription = colorFrame.FrameDescription;
            if (colorFrame.RawColorImageFormat == ColorImageFormat.Bgra)
                colorFrame.CopyRawFrameDataToArray(pixels);
            else
                colorFrame.CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray(this.pixels, ColorImageFormat.Bgra);

            //Initialize Emgu CV image then assign byte array of pixels to it
            Image<Bgr, byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(colorFrameDescription.Width, colorFrameDescription.Height);
            img.Bytes = pixels;

            imgBox.Image = img;//Show image in Emgu.CV.UI.ImageBox
        }
    }
}
```

The converted image is corrupted after zooming more than 25%. Please see below screenshots-

50% Zoom -
[image: 50% Zoom]

25% Zoom -
[image: 25% Zoom]

12.5% Zoom -
[image: 12.5% Zoom]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The < TColor> should be Bgra, you can confirm from the "pixels" bytes array.

edit:
As the intensity of the Kinect's color frame is 0, the image won't be visible, so I added this code to solve the issue, I hope there is a better (faster) way to solve it.

```cs
private void FixIntensity(byte[] p)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < p.Length)
        {
            p[i+3] = 255;
            i += 4;
        }
    }
```